# Propertly form JSON with df.to_json with dataframe containing nested json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following situation:

```
id                                   items
3b68b7b2-f42c-418b-aa88-02450d66b616 [{quantity=3.0, item_id=210defdb-de69-4d03-bddd-7db626cd501b, description=Abc}, {quantity=1.0, item_id=ff457660-5f30-4432-a5af-564a9dee0029, description=xyz . 23}, {quantity=10.0, item_id=8dbd22f2-cc13-4776-b58c-4d6fe0f3463e, description=abc def}]
```

where one of my columns has a nested JSON list inside of it.
I wish to output the data of this dataframe as proper JSON, *including* the nested list.

So, for example, calling `df.to_dict(orient='records', indent=4)` on the above dataframe yields:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "3b68b7b2-f42c-418b-aa88-02450d66b616",
        "items": "[{quantity=3.0, item_id=210defdb-de69-4d03-bddd-7db626cd501b, description=Abc}, {quantity=1.0, item_id=ff457660-5f30-4432-a5af-564a9dee0029, description=xyz . 23}, {quantity=10.0, item_id=8dbd22f2-cc13-4776-b58c-4d6fe0f3463e, description=abc def}]"
    }
]
```

whereas I want:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "3b68b7b2-f42c-418b-aa88-02450d66b616",
        "items": [
            {
                "quantity": 3.0, 
                "item_id": "210defdb-de69-4d03-bddd-7db626cd501b",
                "description": "Abc"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity": 1.0,
                "item_id": "ff457660-5f30-4432-a5af-564a9dee0029",
                "description": "xyz . 23"

            }, 
            {   
                "quantity": 10.0,
                "item_id": "8dbd22f2-cc13-4776-b58c-4d6fe0f3463e",
                "description": "abc def"

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Is this possible using `df.to_json()`? I have tried to use regex to parse the resulting string, but due to the data contained therein, it is unfortunately extremely difficult so "jsonify" the fields I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a list but a string, and this string is not valid json, so you need a bit of pre-processing.

Assuming a non-nested structure, you can use:

```
import json

out = (df.assign(items=df['items'].str.replace(r'(\w+)=([^,}]+)', r'"\1": "\2"', regex=True).apply(json.loads))
         .to_dict(orient='records')
      )
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '3b68b7b2-f42c-418b-aa88-02450d66b616',
  'items': [{'description': 'Abc',
             'item_id': '210defdb-de69-4d03-bddd-7db626cd501b',
             'quantity': '3.0'},
            {'description': 'xyz . 23',
             'item_id': 'ff457660-5f30-4432-a5af-564a9dee0029',
             'quantity': '1.0'},
            {'description': 'abc def',
             'item_id': '8dbd22f2-cc13-4776-b58c-4d6fe0f3463e',
             'quantity': '10.0'}]}]
```

Comment: Or use `.to_json(orient='records', indent=4)` to export as json

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed a string, which I guess threw me off a bit.